# android M - Media recorder writing to pipes issue

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm creating the pipes for my video streaming application. I was using camera2 and it is working perfectly well. but if i use the same code in android M it fails and gives me the following exception.

```
        E/MediaRecorder: start failed: -2147483648
        W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
        W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
```

If i use external SD file instead of output it works perfectly. This issue is only with android m and not with lollipop.

Has anyone faced the similar issue that your video streaming code is broken on Android M? And how was it solved?

Comment: I have same issue with you now, have you already solved it?

Comment: i have same issue,   at android.media.MediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(Native Method)
                                                                        at android.media.MediaRecorder.setProfile(MediaRecorder.java:543)